# Application is not working in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

Before I moved my project from XCode 5 and iOS 7.1 to XCode 6 and iOS 8.0 my application was working in background.

Unfortunately now the method `___repeating` is stop repeat in background. What do I miss? Recently I've made many changes on *developer.apple.com*. This may be the reason? Did Apple change the rules how background application work? Code and Capabilities screen are located below.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(___repeating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)___repeating {
    DLog(@"Working!");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how background processing is supposed to work on iOS. [See Apple's documentation on multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4). In general, you set up your task and wait for the OS to call a particular method, that way your app can sleep between calls. Your app can even be killed completely between calls, and the OS will relaunch it at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thanks, that was I wanted to hear.